# C# - Change label text from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, class, label

I am a total noob on C# and I'm stuck on changing the status label text from an other class.

When this class connects to db I want to change the label text to "Connected":

```
public class DBConnect
{
    public void Connect()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn;
        string myConnectionString;

        myConnectionString = "server = 127.0.0.1; uid=cardb;" +
            "pwd=cardb; database=test;";            

        try
        {
            Form form = new Form();
            conn = new MySqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
            conn.Open();
            form.setStatus();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method setStatus I created in Form class:

```
public partial class Form : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    public Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void setStatus()
    {
        StatusTextLabel.Text = "Connected";
    }
```

The label text doesnt change though.. :/

Comment: I think you are calling `setStatus()` method on incorrect `Form` instance. You have created new `form` instance which is not yet visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no code to create a `DBConnect` object, or to call its `Connect()` method, and no code that makes the Form object visible, e.g. `form.Show()`.

Other than that you probably should not create the Form from the Connect method; instead call `Connect()` from the Form, e.g. in Form_Load(), let it return a status, or better: the `conn` object (which you are now throwing away after connection), and make Form_Load set the Label.Text based on that.

Example code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var conn = new DBConnect().Connect();
    if (conn != null && conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        StatusTextLabel.Text = "Connected";
    }
}

public class DBConnect
{
    public SqlConnection Connect()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = ...
        // ...
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: The second part did the trick. I passed the data to the Form class and I let it make tha changes.

Comment: Now I have this code:

`MySqlDataAdapter MySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from factories", connection.connection);            MessageBox.Show(connection.connection.ToString());
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            MySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];`

But I get a: The name 'dataGridView1' does not exist in the current context error

I have a datagrid ofcourse but I want to pass data to it from MySQL

Comment: You should in most cases do stuff that concerns User Interface objects from code in the Form. The UI object wills not be known elsewhere. You can put the data retrieval methods anywhere you like, but they should simply return the data and that is where their responsibility stops. Then the Form code will send the data to the UI elements.

Comment: This piece of code is inside the Form class. So the class should know its existence right?

Comment: If the compiler can't find it then you did something wrong. Make sure that the method is not labeled `static` and that the method is really defined *inside* the class of your Form. Other than that I have no idea. If needed, please start a *new* question in SO for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the form instead of creating a new one.

```
private Form form {get;set;}

public DBConnect(Form form)
{  
    this.form = form;
}
```

Then try this

```
form.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => form.setStatus()));
```

Comment: You need to pass the form into DBConnect if you want to do it this way? For example, when you create the DB connect, PASS the form then use this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an instance of a new Form, you probably need an instance of already opened form and call the method from there. You can try:

```
(System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form"] as Form).setStatus();
```